# Django ManyToMany field not preselecting rows with custom manager

Tags: django, django-models

Django 1.2.5: I've got a model with a custom manager. Data is saved correctly, but it's not retrieved correctly for related objects.

My models are:

- Question -> related to a SubjectiveStatistic
- SubjectiveStatistic extends Statistic as a Proxy. It has a custom manager to restrict the result set to only where the 'type' field matches 'SubjectiveStatistic' (the type field contains the class name of the object).

Here's the Question:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    subjective_statistic = models.ManyToManyField(SubjectiveStatistic, null=True, blank=True)
```

Here is the SubjectiveStatistic:

```
class SubjectiveStatistic(Statistic):
    ## Use a custom model manager so that the default object collection is
    # filtered by the object class name.
    objects = RestrictByTypeManager('SubjectiveStatistic')

    ## Override the __init__ method to set the type field
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.type = self.__class__.__name__
        return super(SubjectiveStatistic, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Here is the manager:

```
from django.db import models

## Custom model manager that returns objects filtered so that 'type' == a
# given string.
class RestrictByTypeManager(models.Manager):
    def __init__(self, type='', *args, **kwargs):
        self.type = type
        return super(RestrictByTypeManager, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(RestrictByTypeManager, self).get_query_set().filter(type=self.type)
```

What do I need to do so that related objects are returned correctly? question.subjective_statistic.exists() doesn't return anything, despite relations existing in the database.

Perhaps it's because the RestrictByTypeManager extends Manager instead of ManyRelatedManager (but I can't because that's an inner class) or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use your custom manager from the `Question` model, add `use_for_related_fields = True` in the definition of the custom manager:

```
from django.db import models

## Custom model manager that returns objects filtered so that 'type' == a
# given string.
class RestrictByTypeManager(models.Manager):

    use_for_related_fields = True

    def __init__(self, type='', *args, **kwargs):
        self.type = type
        return super(RestrictByTypeManager, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(RestrictByTypeManager, self).get_query_set().filter(type=self.type)
```

This way, `RestrictByTypeManager` will be used as manager for `SubjectiveStatistic` models either directly or in reverse access like with manytomany relations.

More informations here: [Controlling automatic Manager types](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#controlling-automatic-manager-types)

Comment: that hasn't helped unfortunately. it has the same behaviour as before.

Comment: What's the sql output for `question.subjective_statistic.exists()`?

Comment: ah, i didn't know i could do that. the sql is: SELECT (1) AS `a` FROM `console_statistic` INNER JOIN `survey_question_subjective_statistic` ON (`console_statistic`.`id` = `survey_question_subjective_statistic`.`subjectivestatistic_id`) WHERE (`console_statistic`.`type` =   AND `survey_question_subjective_statistic`.`question_id` = 15 ) LIMIT 1'. the console_statistic.type clause is empty.

Comment: so it seems that i need to initialise the RestrictByTypeManager with 'SubjectiveStatistic' in the reverse direction somehow...

Comment: I've just set SubjectiveStatistic as the default value in the constructor and it's working now. Thanks for your help. I'd be interested to know if there's a better way though.